# mock up with jquery load()

Tags: jquery, load

I want to use load()...

```
$('#profilecontainer').load('url/to/datafile');
```

But I need to mock the data. How do I do that? where do I put the datafile and should be in what format? Thank you.

Comment: Further to the above comments, please take a look at the [Mark-down help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format code *as* code.